# gdb: call function in multithreaded program without progressing threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I'm debugging a multithreaded C++ program with gdb. Here's the debugging flow I'd like to achieve:

1. run until a breakpoint, then pause execution for all threads
2. disable [breakpoints] with the `disable` command
3. call a function (defined in my program) to print the state of a vector (while keeping the other threads paused)

However, when I make the call to the function that prints the state of the system multiple times, the values of the data structure change. Unless I have some sort of other bug, this must mean that the other threads are running while my printing function is running.

**Questions:**

1. do other threads resume execution while a `call` command is executed
   in gdb?
2. assuming so, is there a way to disable this such that I can
   keep threads paused while I introspect program state via `call`
   commands?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html is this helpful?

Comment: @KostasRim yes that's exactly what I needed; `set scheduler-locking on` does what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @KostasRim's comment -- `set scheduler-locking on` achieves the desired behavior (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/All_002dStop-Mode.html). By default, other threads run during stepping, function calling, etc.